# Streaming implementation in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My task is to read csv file from local drive. It contains stock data which is updated regularly at certain intervals. Next, perform some operations on the read data and write back to a new csv file on regular intervals.

My code is adapated from **WikipediaAnalysis** code, the problem is that the execution happens only once. After the initial run the program ends and does not remain on running state. It does not run on regular intervals of 5 sec(which I have set) like that of WikipediaAnalysis. Below is my code:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<String> dataStream = getCsvDataStream(see);
DataStream<Stock> edits = dataStream.flatMap(new Tokenizer());
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
KeyedStream<Stock, String> keyedEdits = edits.keyBy(new KeySelector<Stock, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(Stock event) {
                java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) event.getTimeStamp() * 1000);
                return time.toString();
            }
        });

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
DataStream<Tuple2<Double, Double>> result = keyedEdits.timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
                .fold(new Tuple2<>(0.0d, 0.0d), new FoldFunction<Stock, Tuple2<Double, Double>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Double, Double> fold(Tuple2<Double, Double> acc, Stock event) {
                        acc.f0 = event.getClose();
                        acc.f1 = event.getOpen();                           
                        return acc;
                    }
                });
```

Could you please suggest!!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "is does not run on regular interval of 5 sec"? Furthermore, can you please share the code of `getCsvDataStream()`. Does your source re-read the files that gets updated over and over again? If your source read the file only once, the program terminate automatically because it assumes that it processed all data (because files are finite)